# Bad response with axios call in laravel

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, vue.js, axios

I'm trying to figure out what's going on here, but I've set my Vue instance to hit an axios call every time a new tag is added. The problem is I keep getting a 400 bad request and I can't figure out why.

When I add a tag and inspect my Vue element, my object is `tag_data: "test string"`. I just want to make the call with "test string" as my data.

Any obvious issues with what I'm doing?

Route

```
Route::post('tags/save','CampaignsController@saveTags')
    ->name('tags/save');
```

Controller

```
public function saveTags(Request $request)
{
    $tagData = $request->tag_data;

    $stmt->bindValue(1,$tagData, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindParam(2, $out2, PDO::PARAM_INT|PDO::PARAM_INPUT_OUTPUT);

    $stmt->execute();
}
```

Blade

```
new Vue({
  components: {
    Multiselect: window.VueMultiselect.default
  },
  el: "#tagApp",
  data() {
    return{
        value: [],
        loading: false,
        options: []
    }

  },
  methods: {
    read: function(val){

      if (val) {
        this.loading = true;
        this.options = [];

      } else {
        this.options = [];
      }
    },

    /*Issue is here*/
    addTag(newTag) {
      const tag = {
        tag_data: newTag,
      };
      this.options.push(tag);
      this.value.push(tag);

      axios.post('campaigns/tags/save',{
            tag_data: newTag,
      })
      .then(function (response){
            console.log(response);
      })
      .catch(function (error) {
            console.log(error);
            console.log(tag_data);
      });
    }
  }
})
```

Comment: is your axios configured to set the csrf token?

Comment: secondly, how come you're using raw PDO? Eloquent comes with Laravel

Comment: I actually just condensed it for the code on here but I am using an eloquent instance. This is just for testing purposes. But yes it's configured for the csrf token

Comment: thirdly, you're incorrectly defining a vue method. it should be `addTag: function(newTag) { ... } `

Comment: Does your axios call reach Laravel method?

Comment: Your route is `tags/save` but your post is hitting `campaigns/tags/save`

Comment: @TomN. Are you returning 400 response anywhere from your Laravel code?

Comment: @AshleyBrown author might be using route groups, so his `tags/save` could be wrapped in group with `campaigns` prefix :)

Comment: @vivek_23 no it just shows on the axios call

Comment: @Tarasovych That's correct, I'm using route groups

Comment: @TomN. Try it from Postman first. If it succeeds, then issue is in your frontend.

Comment: @vivek_23 it fails on postman as well

Comment: @AshleyBrown wait I don't believe it is set for token actually

Comment: @vivek_23 I actually got it to reach the method now and it says call to function bindValue() on null, though it shows in the request payload as a string

Comment: @TomN. What was the issue though? Also, `null` issue is on the `$stmt` variable and not on request payload.

Comment: Right but it's saying bindValue is occurring on null, which is coming from the $tagData variable and that's set by my request->tag_data. That's what shows in the browser payload

Comment: @TomN. What does `var_dump($stmt)` give you?